# Are Romulan scientists involved in politics?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, romulan

In the middle of "[The Next Phase](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Next_Phase_(episode))" episode of Star Trek: The Next Generation, a Romulan scientific officer (the top rank one at that moment) decides to destroy the Enterprise. This is clearly political and diplomatic decision in Romulan vs. Federation war.

This decision (and attitude) is completely different from what we can see in the "[Eye of the Neddle](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Eye_of_the_Needle)" episode of Star Trek: Voyager. Where Romulan scientist clearly declares that the only reason for him to help Voyager crew is, because he is a scientist, not involved in any kind of politic "games" between Romulan and Federation.

I wonder, if Romulan scientist are really involved in politics and which of these two behaviors more closely describes majority of Romulan scientists?

Comment: I think you're falling into the common trap of trying to over-generalise an entire species. The Romulan race is HUGE. There are _billions_ of scientists, both inside and outside of the military machine. Why do you think we can generalise about them like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All scientists are, well, "human"; Meaning that everyone, even scientists, have opinions, beliefs, politics both left and right, etc. that can influence and bias their work. That's why the [*scientific method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method#Peer_review_evaluation) was developed. With it's emphasis on repeatability and peer review, the scientific method does a lot to weed out personal and political bias and leave objectively correct results. It's not perfect - [nothing is](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SturgeonsLaw) - but it's the best tool anyone's come up with so far.
So to answer your question, Romulan scientists come in all flavors, from rigid government-conformist tools to fringe-wing radicals - just like human scientists.